# Using wp_localize_script to get data from cpt and pass it to maplace-js locations

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, json, wp-localize-script

I'm currently building an Dealerlocator with ACF and CPT.

For the dealerlocator to shop the dealers on the map I want to use MAPlace-JS. This works fine when adding an array to the locations variable manually.

When passing data from my CPT it throws me an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string.

This is the JSON array which is passed:

```
    [{
    "lat":"52.5164364",
    "lng":"6.073328800000013",
    "title":"Company Name",
    "zoom":8, 
    "icon":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/mapfiles\/markerA.png"
    },{
    "lat":"53.3354151",
    "lng":"6.5032264999999825",
    "title":"Company Name 2",
    "zoom":8,
    "icon":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/mapfiles\/markerA.png"
    }]
```

This is passed via the following script:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

  global $post;
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'dealers'
  );

  $mapposts = get_posts($args);
  $location_array = array();

  foreach($mapposts as $mappost) : setup_postdata($mappost);

    $location = get_field('maps_location', $mappost->ID);
    $location_array[] = array(
      'lat' => $location['lat'],
      'lng' => $location['lng'],
            'title' => get_the_title($mappost->ID),
            'zoom' => 8,
            'icon' => 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png'
    );

    $location_json = json_encode($location_array);

    wp_localize_script('sage/main.js', 'locationJSON', $location_json);

  endforeach;


}, 110);
```

And on the JS file called like this:

```
console.log(locationJSON);
new Maplace({
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  locations: locationJSON,
  controls_type: 'list',
  controls_on_map: false,
}).Load();
```

On the console.log it shows the JSON as above, so the code is passed ok.

But the code is not working within the Maps script, this is the error below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string '[{"lat":"52.5164364","lng":"6.073328800000013","title":"Company Name","zoom":8,"icon":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/mapfiles\/markerA.png"},{"lat":"53.3354151","lng":"6.5032264999999825","title":"Company Name 2","zoom":8,"icon":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/mapfiles\/markerA.png"}]'
    at b._init (maplace.min.js:12)
    at b.Load (maplace.min.js:12)
    at Object.init (common.js:15)
    at Router.fire (Router.js:30)
    at Router.loadEvents (Router.js:45)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:25)
    at i (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2)
b._init @ maplace.min.js:12
b.Load @ maplace.min.js:12
init @ common.js:15
fire @ Router.js:30
loadEvents @ Router.js:45
(anonymous) @ main.js:25
i @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.12.4.min.js:2
```

I'm searching for this for hours now, but I'm not able to solve this thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `json_encode()` when using `wp_localize_script()`. The last argument of `wp_localize_script()` should be a *PHP* array. This will be converted to JSON for you.

So to resolve the issue, remove this line:

```
$location_json = json_encode($location_array);
```

And change `wp_localize_script()` to use `$location_array`:

```
wp_localize_script('sage/main.js', 'locationJSON', $location_array);
```

Because `$location_array` had been double-encoded the `locationJSON` variable was actually just a text string that *looked like* JSON. So when the Maplace script tried to access the first element of the array with `locationJSON[0]` it failed because the `locationJSON` variable was not actually an Array.

Comment: This shows me at least the MAPlace locations. But the complete site is not responding anymore and google maps is crashing (it won't load the actual map). I use [link](https://maplacejs.com) the Menu variant.

Comment: That would be unrelated to anything you've asked about here, or my answer.

Comment: Well, that's my question... How am I able to fix it. It does work with the example array from maplace-js